# How to make an existing AutoIncrement index become the Clustered Index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, clustered-index

This is a bit puzzling.

I have a unique non-clustered index I want to turn into the clustered index for that table.

I can't drop and recreate the index, because dropping the index on the AI column is illegal.

here's the current DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `RETS_STAGE1_QUEUE` (
  `LN_LIST_NUMBER` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `RECORDMODDATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `syncTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `xmlText` varchar(64000) NOT NULL,
  `RETS_STAGE1_QUEUE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `RETS_STAGE1_QUEUE_ID` (`RETS_STAGE1_QUEUE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=838053 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the table? What is the current clustered index?

Comment: I already dropped the old clustered index, so there is none at the moment. DDL added to question.

Answer (score 1):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is already being used as the clustered index.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html):

> > If you do not define a PRIMARY KEY for your table, MySQL locates the first UNIQUE index where all the key columns are NOT NULL and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.

Comment: is there any advantage to converting the UNIQUE to PRIMARY KEY or should I just leave it alone then?

Comment: @AlexR I would, because that is effectively what it is, readability is advantage enough.